# Why do rooms adjacent to our kitchen experience condensation on the walls?

Tags: walls, leak, roof

We started having the issue from last year in one of our lounge rooms. When it is cold, and especially when we start cooking in the next room, the smaller lounge room starts dripping from all sides of the room. We are thinking from condensation but do not understand why this is suddenly happening as we never had this issue years before. It now starting to cause cracks and mold and we have called a few roofers/builders to advise on the issue, but they really have no idea of the cause. Also one suggested replacing the felt under the roof but charging a lot of money with no guarantee the issue will be resolved. We already have vents on the roof.

This room is part of an extension that was done roughly 10 years ago. The issues started from last year.

It does not have a room upstairs so cannot be a upstairs bathroom problem. Just to clarify it is an extension with no room above. Roofers have checked the roof/tiles and cannot find any missing tiles and confirmed we have the correct amount of ventilators on the roof. The roof above is NOT flat.

The middle of the ceiling is fine, problem starts from the top edges of the ceiling. We thought this could be a gutter issue but the issue is happening on all four sides of the room

We did fit a new ventilator for the oven a few years ago and someone checked that it was all okay as the pipe goes up to the roof. The person did not seem to find an issue with it and we have windows open when cooking.

We cannot hear any leaks in the ceiling/wall.

[image]

I wanted to add a video and more pictures, but does not allow me for some reason. The video would have been good.
Thank you!

Comment: What, if any, insulation is above this room? What, if any ventilation is in the cooking room next door? Please [edit] that information into your question.

Comment: What's above your lounge room ceilings?  Are those ceilings the underside of the roof, or is there an attic space between those ceilings and the roof itself?

Comment: No other room above, just the roof. I have edited my post to clarify. The roof is not flat and the roofer who came confirmed all tiles seemed fine condition and no missing tiles.

Comment: A thermal camera might be really helpful here. How do you heat that room?

Comment: We have also been having issues with our radiators which do not work very well, but we still use them to heat up the room. We've had this issues with the radiators for many years but this problem only started from last year

Comment: I would expect condensation more uniform up and down the wall, but that assumes uniform insulation in the wall cavity. I can imagine a wetness pattern like that if the top foot of the wall cavities was left uninsulated. Does the wetness correlate with outdoor weather conditions? Can you refrain from cooking moisture into the air for a month or so to observe whether the condition improves?

Comment: If its condensation from cooking gases, then you should be able to verify it by tracing where it is ducted.  Maybe its fallen apart.

Comment: You mentioned radiators for heating.  Is this a steam heating system, or circulating hot water?

Answer (score 3):

The correlation with cooking the dripping around the upper perimeter of the lounge suggest water vapor from cooking is spreading from the kitchen through the air.  Warm air rises, and humid air deposits water when it hits cool surfaces. The ceiling center may be better insulated than the edges and thus warmer.

1. You could test this by closing off the kitchen while cooking to see if the dripping stops.  I would try this first as it is free and easy.
2. If it does, can you close off the kitchen and/or vent one or both rooms to the outdoors?
3. If dripping continues or happens irrespective of cooking, consider there may be more than one cause.

If the problem persists, you may get some clues by gathering more data under various conditions (indoor/outdoor temp/humidity).  Imaging from a thermal camera (as mentioned by @UnhandledExcepSean) might suggest locations to explore.  A less sophisticated (but much less expensive tool) for exploring temperatures at a distance is a Digital Infrared Thermometer Gun, under $10, which you aim at a target and read its temperature.  Scanning the walls and ceiling even plotting a temperature map under various conditions might help, if it comes to that.